# Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC al exportar de DataGridView a Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excepciones

Buen día, tengo un problema al intentar exportar el contenido de un dataGridView a Excel, únicamente me arroja excepción cuando intento exportar una cantidad muy grande de filas (arriba de 3mil), hice la prueba con menos filas y se exporta sin problemas (aunque tarda bastante).

Cualquier sugerencia me ayudaría bastante, tanto para solucionar la excepción como para hacer el proceso más eficiente.

[image: Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC]

El código con el que exporto a Excel es el siguiente:

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:";
                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Exportar a Excel";
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Reporte";
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel (2007 en adelante)|*.xlsx| Excel (2003 y versiones antiguas)|*.xls";
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                    for (int i = 1; i < tabla.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        excel.Cells[1, i] = tabla.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < tabla.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            excel.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tabla.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;

                        }
                    }
                    excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
                    excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
                    excel.Quit();
                    MessageBox.Show("Excel generado", "Correcto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ha ocurrido un error al general el Excel \n " + ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

De ser posible no uses las librerias `Interop` de `Office` para generar el `excel`, usa librerias basadas en `open xml`, como ser

[ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki)

como explica este ejemplo

[Export DataGridView to Excel with Formatting using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataGridView-to-Excel-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

la idea es que teniendo el datatable puede exportar sin problemas con componente COM

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Customers");

    //Set the color of Header Row.
    //A resembles First Column while C resembles Third column.
    wb.Worksheet(1).Cells("A1:C1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.DarkGreen;
    for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //A resembles First Column while C resembles Third column.
        //Header row is at Position 1 and hence First row starts from Index 2.
        string cellRange = string.Format("A{0}:C{0}", i + 1);
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(cellRange).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.GreenYellow;
        }
        else
        {
            wb.Worksheet(1).Cells(cellRange).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Yellow;
        }

    }
    //Adjust widths of Columns.
    wb.Worksheet(1).Columns().AdjustToContents();

    //Save the Excel file.
    wb.SaveAs(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.xlsx");
}
```

Aunque tambien hay una forma mas directa si usas

```
wb.Worksheets.Add(dataTable);
```

ya que la libreria soporta exportar directo

En resumen recomiendo evites las librerias `COM` ve a una basada en `open xml`

[Adding DataTable as Worksheet](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet)